# boost asio "A non-recoverable error occurred during database lookup"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm currently stress testing my server.

sometimes I get "A non-recoverable error occurred during database lookup" Error
coming from **error.message()**

error is sent to my handling function by **boost::asio::placeholders::error** called on the **async_read method**.

I have no idea what this error means, and I am not able to reproduce purposely this error, it only happen sometimes and seems to be random (of course it is not, but it seems)

Does anyone have ever got this error message, and if so, know where it came from ?

---

### EDIT 1

Here's what I found on the boost library, the error is :

**no_recovery = BOOST_ASIO_NETDB_ERROR(NO_RECOVERY)**

But can't figure out what this is...

---

### EDIT 2

Just so you know everything about my problem, here the design :

I have only one io_service.
Everytime a user is connecting, an async_read is starting, waiting for something to read.
When it reads something, most of the time, it is doing some work on a thread (coming from a pool), and write something synchronously back to the user. (using boost write).
Even since boost 1.37 claims that synchronous write is thread safe, I'm really worried about the fact that it is coming from this.

If the user sends different message really quick, it can happen that async_read and write are called simultaneously, can it does any harm ?

---

### EDIT 3

Here's some portion of my code asked by Dave S :

```
    void TCPConnection::listenForCMD() {
    boost::asio::async_read(m_socket,
                            boost::asio::buffer(m_inbound_data, 3),
                            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(3),
                            boost::bind(&TCPConnection::handle_cmd,
                                        shared_from_this(),
                                        boost::asio::placeholders::error)
                            );
  }

      void TCPConnection::handle_cmd(const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        if (error) {
          std::cout << "ERROR READING : " << error.message() << std::endl;
    return;
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          std::string str1(m_inbound_data);
          std::string str = str1.substr(0,3);

          std::cout << "COMMAND FUNCTION: " << str << std::endl;

          a_fact func = CommandFactory::getInstance()->getFunction(str);

          if (func == NULL) {
            std::cout << "command doesn't exist: " << str << std::endl;
            return;
          }

          protocol::in::Command::pointer cmd = func(m_socket, client);

          cmd->setCallback(boost::bind(&TCPConnection::command_is_done,
                                       shared_from_this()));
          cmd->parse();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      }
```

m_inbound_data is a char[3]

Once cmd->parse() is done, it will call a callback **command_is_done**

```
  void TCPConnection::command_is_done() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    m_inbound_data[0] = '0';
    m_inbound_data[1] = '0';
    m_inbound_data[2] = '0';

    listenForCMD();
  }
```

The error occurs in the **handle_cmd** when checking for error at the first line.

As I said before, the cmd->parse() will parse the command it just got, sometime lauching blocking code in a thread coming from a pool. On this thread it sends back data to the client with a synchronous write.

**IMPORTANT THING :** The callback **command_is_done** will always be called before the said thread is launched. this means that **listenForCMD** is already called when the thread may send something back to the client in synchronous write. Therefore my first worries.

Comment: So, you now know where it came from...?

Comment: unfortunately, no. This is just addition to help further to find the issue...

Comment: What OS is this on?  Digging a bit shows that it has something to do with the address lookup in asio.

Comment: Not sure it is coming from OS, because the server is a debian, my laptop is a mac OS X, and I get the same issue... (Thing is, it is not windows)

Comment: When you say address lookup, that would probably mean a unallocated (or freed) pointer ?

Comment: Rather than describe the problem with words, post your code.

Comment: My code is close to a thousand lines and tens of files. There is no easy way to post it. Sorry. Just looking for someone who may know what exactly means the error I get.

Comment: @TheSquad: No, I believe it has to do with IP<->Name lookup.  Specifically, it looks like it's an error for gethostbyname() (or some equivalent).  The problem with that is that async_read shouldn't be returning that, but it should be an error for the resolve or async_resolve calls.

Comment: Can you post at least the call to the async_read?

Comment: @TheSquad you should boil the problem down to a complete reproducer that can be posted in the question. Doing so will help you understand the problem, and it will help us provide better answers.

Comment: @Dave S : This is the server side, It does not have any async_resolve or resolver of any kind... I'll post my async_read in a minute

Comment: @Sam Miller : I agree, i'll try to do my best, but i'm concerned that I would left out something important if I try to reproduce in brief my code...

Comment: You cannot do multiple synchronous or asynchronous reads or writes on the same socket. You can do read and write at the same time, but not multiple operations of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When it reads something, most of the time, it is doing some work on a
> thread (coming from a pool), and write something synchronously back to
> the user. (using boost write). **Even since boost 1.37 claims that
> synchronous write is thread safe**, I'm really worried about the fact
> that it is coming from this.

Emphasis added by me, this is incorrect. A single `boost::asio::tcp::socket` is not thread safe, the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) is very clear

> *Thread Safety*
>
> **Distinct objects:** Safe.
>
> **Shared objects**: Unsafe.

It is also very odd to mix `async_read()` with a blocking `write()`.

Comment: How come this is stated in boost documentation ? http://beta.boost.org/users/history/minimal.php/version_1_37_0 the exact sentence is "Synchronous read, write, accept and connect operations are now thread safe (meaning that it is now permitted to perform concurrent synchronous operations on an individual socket, if supported by the OS)."

Comment: @TheSquad without looking into the 1.36 implementation, I suspect there was a mutex used internally. As evident by the clause **if supported by the OS**, it is not a universal truth. In general, interleaving read operations on a socket is not safe.